# Having trouble passing parent function to child component

Tags: reactjs

Using info on StackOverflow, I've tried to pass a parent function to a child component via props; however, I keep running into errors when doing so. To simplify, here is my parent function:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dailyPreloadMetrics: null,
      queryResults: [0,0],
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

   handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  onClick(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({isHidden: true});
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/kw-finder', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
      body: JSON.stringify({'firstParam': event.target.value,
                            'secondParam' : 300000})
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
        this.setState({queryResults: JSON.parse(json['query_results']),
                       dailyPreloadMetrics: JSON.parse(json['keyword_data']),
                       })
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <QueryResultButtons data={this.state.queryResults}
                          onClick={this.onClick}
                          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

My Child component is as follows:

```
class DynamicButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      secondParam: this.props.audienceMax
      }
  }


  render() {
    const {
      data
    } = this.props
    const row = this.props.data && data.map((data) =>
        <Button style={{margin: "10px"}}
                value={data}
               onClick={e => this.props.onClick(e)}
                name='value'
                >
        </Button>

        )
    return (row)
  }
}

class QueryResultButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
               <div>
                  <h1>Did you mean any of these instead?</h1>
                  <DynamicButton data={this.props.data && this.props.data}/>
              </div>
    )
}
}

export default QueryResultButtons
```

Basically I am trying to pass a function - `onClick` - from the parent to the two levels of child components (down to the DynamicButton Child Component). However, when I try this action, I get an error message stating: _this3.props.onClick is not a function. It seems the Child component isn't picking up the parent function but not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert the `QueryResultButtons` component you are passing the `onClick` function like `onClick={this.onClick}` but when you call the `DynamicButton` you are not passing the `onClick` function:

```
<DynamicButton data={this.props.data && this.props.data}/>
```

Try this:

```
<DynamicButton data={this.props.data && this.props.data} onClick={this.props.onClick}/>
```

The `QueryResultButtons` should be:

```
class QueryResultButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
               <div>
                  <h1>Did you mean any of these instead?</h1>
                  <DynamicButton data={this.props.data && this.props.data}
                                 onClick={this.props.onClick}
                  />
              </div>
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DynamicButton` component is not direct child of `App` component, it is grandchild. So you have to pass `onClick` function from child component (`QueryResultButtons`) to grandchild component (`DynamicButton`) as well.

So, replace you `QueryResultButtons` with this:

```
class QueryResultButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Did you mean any of these instead?</h1>
        <DynamicButton
          data={this.props.data && this.props.data}
          onClick={this.props.onClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```